# 2 Diffferent templates for the same single Taxonomy Page (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, templates, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to have 2 different templates for the same signle taxonomy page? I Know how to create it for regular page, but never did it for taxonomy page and option on backend to switch it.

Is it possible and how?

P.s  Single taxonomy template is -> single-practice-area.php

I tried to create 2nd template adding something like this
/*
Template Name: 2nd template
*/
but that doesn't work